# What can be done with broken Humanoid bot in Vault 0 Cryogenics area?

Tags: fallout-tactics

I have found this broken Humanoid bot in Vault 0 Cryogenics area, I have tried talking but no dialogue would appear also using science and repair skills on him without luck.

[image]
**Is there a quest or something that can be done with this robot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That robot is probably HR-0Y2, aka 'Heroy'. [According to the fallout tactics speech files](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/MIS_25_Speech.txt) the robot can be repaired with a high enough science or repair skill, at which point it will attack the player.